# How do you combine two point clouds with comma?

Tags: csv, binary, abyss

I was wondering whether the following would work:

```
cat file1 file1 | csv-sort --binary 4f --fields x,y,z,a --unique > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `csv-paste`

```
csv-paste "file1.bin;binary=ui,ui,ui" "file2.bin;binary=ui" > file3.bin
```